# Could not cast value of type 'TableViewController' to 'TableViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to pass Realm data from Custom cell to Detail TableView Controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "viewTask" {
        let nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  TaskViewTableViewController
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath!
        let task = tasks![indexPath.row]
        nextViewController.name = task.name
        nextViewController.notes = task.notes
        nextViewController.date = task.date
        nextViewController.timeLength = task.timeLength
    }
}
```

I'm getting error

> Could not cast value of type 'Taskio.TaskListTableViewController'
>   (0x10001f028) to 'Taskio.TaskViewTableViewController' (0x10001f280).

**Also tried**

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "viewTask" {
            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  TaskViewTableViewController
            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath!
            let task = tasks![indexPath.row]
            nextViewController.name = task.name
            nextViewController.notes = task.notes
            nextViewController.date = task.date
            nextViewController.timeLength = task.timeLength
        }
    }
```

**and also**

```
let nextViewController :  TaskViewTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  TaskViewTableViewController
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to put class name into storyboard of tableViewController. It's **working**

Comment: Title is really misleading.  Title leads me to believe that you've come across some interesting scenario in Swift.  Question body indicates otherwise (because the actual error message isn't even remotely close to what you put in the title).

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, and since I am new to Xcode I do not understand your statement "Forgot to put class name into storyboard of TableViewController". Can you show the code please?

Comment: Forget it. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `destinationViewController` is not of the type that you are expecting. You will need to check the segue to make sure it's pointing to the correct controller. If it is, you'll need to revisit your controller class hierarchy.

Are `TaskListTableViewController` and `TaskViewTableViewController` part of the same class hierarchy? Per the [Swift docs on typecasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html), you can only downcast from `TaskListTableViewController` to `TaskViewTableViewController` if your List view is a subclass of your Task view. It is not enough that both are simply subclasses of `UITableViewController`.

In other words, if your class hierarchy looks like this, you will **not** be able to downcast from the List view to the Task view:

```
                      ----> TaskListTableViewController
                     /
UITableViewController
                     \
                      ----> TaskViewTableViewController
```

But if your hierarchy looks like this, you will be able to downcast from one to the other:

```
UITableViewController -> TaskListTableViewController -> TaskViewTableViewController
```

---

Regarding your second attempt at casting to `UINavigationController`, the navigation controller is not related to `UITableViewController` at all, so it cannot be type casted to that class either.

You can check out the inheritance hierarchy for [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html) and [`UITableViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html). One needs to be a subclass of the other for any type casting to work. You'll see that is not the case.

Comment: my hierarchy looks like your second

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was i forgot to put class name in storyboard

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If I understand from the error message, you are attempting to cast a TaskListTableViewController to TaskViewTableViewController.

The destination is a TaskListTableViewController so you have to treat it like one.

```
let nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  TaskListTableViewController
```

Comment: 1. I tried it if you can read whole my post. and 2. Trying to cast TaskListTableViewController to TaskViewTableViewController not reversed so destination is TaskViewTableViewController

Comment: That's the thing. Your destination is not a TaskViewTableViewController.

Comment: Your code is bad. Because TaskList is Controller from what i want to pass data to TaskView... I fixed it I just forgot to put class name to storyboard controller. But anyway appreciate it that you want to help.